Excel - Dynamically generate loan interest payment schedule
I am building payment schedule for loans. I have raw input data of loan's information and finding way to dynamically generate payment dates with due amount in Excel table.
The raw data of input information looks like:

Expected output looks like (the last M column just for more clear and it is not necessary)

(Loan1 interest follows its frequency for the first 2 payment, last payment is principal + rest of interest)
I can try manual way as legacy excel but it faces too much human error with more loans and changes.
Or =LET(SEQUENCE) helps somehow, but it cannot solve case of last irregular payment of Loan1, and LET can use for single loan only.

Why not just put the first date (correctly formatted in Excel) and the add the requisite number of days ie 120, 160 etc As Excel stores the date as a serial number adding one changes the date by one day.

Your last payment for Loan 1 type shows 9961.67 is it correct? As far i understand the last one will be 10012.77 and calculation i reach at by =C2+C2*F2*((E2-D2)/360)-SUM(Last_Two_Interest_Payments) is there any typo there. But you can see the Loan 2 is giving correct output as well as the first two interest of Loan1 as well. Can you please confirm

Oops, that was my bad, @MayukhBhattacharya, thank you. I have edited.
